# Estimating the recurrence  $T(n,i) = (\lfloor\frac{n-i}{i}\rfloor \cdot i ) + T(i + (n \operatorname{rem} i), (n \operatorname{rem} i))$

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relations

Given $i < n/2$ and denoting $[x]$ to be an integer part of $x$ (floor$(x)$) and
$(a \operatorname{rem} b)$ to be a reminder when $a$ is divided by $b$.

$$
  T(n,i) = \left(\left\lfloor\frac{n-i}{i}\right\rfloor \cdot i\right) + T\left(i + (n \operatorname{rem} i), (n \operatorname{rem} i)\right)
$$
then is $T(n,i) = O(n)$?

Comment: What is $T(n, 0)$?

Comment: T(n,0) = 0 and T(n,1) = n

Comment: I'm not sure if the following makes any sense or even correct. Anyways it might help you towards a correct answer. Fix an $i < n/2$. Then we have $\lfloor \frac{n-i}{i} \rfloor < n-1$, and $n \bmod i < i-1$. Hence $T(n, i) <$ $(n-1) +$ $T(2i-1, i-1)$. If $i$ is fixed to a constant, then $T(n, i) < n-1,$ hence $T(n, i)$ $\in$ $\mathcal{O}(n)$. Continuing on this gibberish, if $i$ is not constant: we actually have $T(n, i)$ $<$ $(n-1)$ $+ (n-2)$ $+ \cdots +$ $(n-i)$ $\in$ $\mathcal{O}(ni - i^2)$ $\in$ $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$.

Comment: Proceeding on the lines of analysis for Euclid's GCD algorithm we can actually say T(n,i) = O(nLogn). I want to know if we can better analyse the sum and actually say it is O(n) or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, rewrite it a bit: $rem \to mod$. $\left\lfloor\frac{n-i}{i}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{n}{i}-1\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{n}{i}\right\rfloor-1$

$$T(n,i) = \left(\left\lfloor\frac{n}{i}\right\rfloor-1\right)i + T\left(i +(n\operatorname{mod}i), (n \operatorname{mod} i)\right)$$

Consider $n=ki+l$, where $k-$non-negative integer, $l-$integer such that $0\le l<i$. Notice that we always can express $n$ in such way.

Then, 
$$
T(n,i)= (k-1)i+T(i+l,l)=n-l-i+T(i+l,l)
$$
Now, consider $i=ml+h$, where $m-$non-negative integer, $h-$integer, $0\le h<l$.

Then,
$$
T(i+l,l)=ml+T(l+h,h)=i-h+T(l+h,h)
$$
So, we've got repetitive pattern, which ends when we encouter $T(x,1)$ or $T(x,0)$.

Let us denote $i=a_0$, $l=a_1$, $h=a_2$ and so on, where general term is $a_{p+1}=a_{p-1}\operatorname{mod}a_p$, then 
$$
\begin{align*} T(n,i) &= n-a_0-a_1+T(a_0+a_1,a_1)=\\
 &= n-a_1-a_2+T(a_1+a_2,a_2)=\\
 &= n-a_2-a_3+T(a_2+a_3,a_3)=\\
 &= \dots =\\
 &= n-a_{p-1}-a_p+T(a_{p-1}+a_p,a_p)
\end{align*}
$$
Hence, in case of $\color{red}{a_p=1}\to T(a_{p-1}+a_p,a_p)=a_{p-1}+a_p$

$$
\color{red}{T(n,i)=n}
$$
In case of $\color{red}{a_p=0}\to T(a_{p-1}+a_p,a_p)=0$
$$
\color{red}{T(n,i)=n-a_{p-1}\to O(n)}
$$
Notice, that in last case $2\le a_{p-1}<n/2$, where lower bound comes from the fact that evaluation didn't stop in first case brach. Upper bound comes from restriction $i<n/2$ stated in task.

Thus, we can combine both cases 
$$
\color{red}{T(n,i)\to O(n),\quad C\in[1/2,1]}
$$
where $C$ is a constant hidden behind $O(n)$.