# Recurrence relation $a_{n+2}=a_n\operatorname{mod}a_{n+1}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, recurrence-relations

While working on [linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188976/estimating-the-recurrence-tn-i-lfloor-fracn-ii-rfloor-cdot-i-t/1934173#1934173), I encountered recurrence relation of form:
$$
a_{n+2}=a_n\operatorname{mod}a_{n+1},\quad a_0=A,\quad a_1=B,
$$ 
where $A,B-$positive integers, $A<B$.

I wonder if there exists a technique to get general term, few terms before $a_n$ turns into $0$, or at least number of iterations before $a_n$ turns into $0$.

Comment: It looks a lot like Euclide's algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sequence is basically the intermediate results from the Euclidean algorithm applied to $A, B$. There's no "general term", it is very easy to calculate the terms, and for the number of nonzero elements in the sequence, you can e.g. read [What is the time complexity of Euclid's Algorithm (Upper bound,Lower Bound and Average)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258596/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-euclids-algorithm-upper-bound-lower-bound-and-a)